# Excel Vlookup in the same workbook but different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a workbook which has two sheets.  What I am trying to do is to Update the service entry worksheet, column UpdatedPartID with the CorrectedID from Parts sheet.

The corresponding column for PartID in PartsWorksheet is OLDID and the row next to it is the ID I want.  i did a vlook formula for instance =VLOOKUP(CELL,SECONDWORKSHEET!COLUMNRANGE,2,0) but I do not get the correct results. I have added below how the sample data sho

```
CurrentData
ServiceEntry Worksheet1
Part ID     UpdatedPartID
1
2
3
4
5

DesiredData
ServiceEntry Worksheet1
Part ID     UpdatedPartID
1           21
2           26
3           1300
4           1200
5           435

Parts Worksheet2
OLD_ID    CorrectedID
10         99
4          1200
3          1300
5          435
1          21
2          26
```

Comment: I got it working, my sheet2 was not referenced correctly in teh vlookup formula.

Comment: That's great did the article help at all or did you just realize your mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some information you might find useful on excel forum. 
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/553681-using-vlookup-across-two-separate-worksheets.html
VLOOKUP(Sheet1,Sheet2)

Comment: I got it working, my sheet2 was not referenced correctly in teh vlookup formula.

Comment: @Griffin: We frown on “answers” that are just a link to a site outside Stack Exchange.  Either present the information, ideally cleaning it up a little (and giving the reference to the source), or assume that the question asker can use a search engine as well as you can.

Comment: @Scott I would of given an example but I was slightly confused myself. I had previous experience and I was trying to recall it but I was failing. Since I couldn't make sense of it due to my bad memory I figured the asker knew the basics and would understand this.